# Universal property of $R[x_1...x_n]/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

For a commutative ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ in $R[x_1...x_n]$, what is the universal property of $R[x_1...x_n]/I$ in the category of R-algebras, $RAlg$?

For example, if I consider $\mathbb{Z}[x_1...x_n]/I$, since $\mathbb{Z}Alg \cong CRing$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x_1...x_n]$ is Noetherian, I can deduce that $\mathbb{Z}Alg(\mathbb{Z}[x_1...x_n]/I, R) \cong [(r_1...r_n) \in \prod_{i=1}^n R: f_1(r_1...r_n) = ... = f_m(r_1...r_n) = 0$], where $I = (f_1...f_n)$. However, I'm not sure what we can say in general, and if we can say anything beyond the usual quotient universal property. I think we should be able to, given that $R[x_1...x_n]$ is the free $R-$algebra on a set.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

1. Let $S$ be an $R$-algebra and $I \subseteq S$ be an ideal. What is the universal property of $S/I$? (in terms of $S$)
2. What is the universal property of $R[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]?$ in the category of $R$-algebras?
3. Can you combine the above two hints to yield a universal property for $R[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]/I$?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was able to do this in the case that $R = \mathbb{Z}$, because then we know that all ideals $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1...x_n]$ are finitely generated. However, for a general (non-Noetherian possibly) ring $R$, this might not be true, so it seems like no statement can be made on the level of certain generating elements of our ideal (like in my post above). Because I don't have these particular elements in general, this is why I'm having some trouble on step (3) of your hint.

Comment: Does finite-generation matter? You can simply talk about vanishing for all $f \in I$.

Answer (score 1):

An $R$-algebra morphism from $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ to $S$ is determined uniquely by a choice of $s_1,\dots,s_n\in S$ such that for all $f\in I$, $f(s_1,\dots,s_n)=0$. In other words, $\mathrm{Hom}(R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I,S)$ is in natural bijection with $V(I)\subseteq S^n$.

If $J\subseteq I$ generates $I$ as an ideal, then it is equivalent to just look at all $f\in J$ in the description above. In particular, if $R$ is Noetherian, then by Hilbert's Basis Theorem, $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is Noetherian, so we can pick a finite set $J$ of generators for any ideal. But you don't need a finite set of generators to make sense of the universal property.